# jQuery hover Opacity and Click Stay on Opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Good morning,

So i have the 2 following sniplets which work great apart from 1 thing that i cannot work out how to resolve. first is a hover state so when you hover the opacity is at 100%, by default its at 70% and when you mouse out it reverts to 70% which is great, the 2nd is a click function that shows a checked image when clicked which is great and the opacity stays at 100% but when you mouse out of the container it reverts back to 70% opacity. is there anyway that is clicked it stays at 100% regardless if you mouse out?

```
$(".opacity-change img").css('opacity','0.7');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".opacity-change img").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.7 }, 500); 
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.profiles a').bind('click',function(){
        $('.checked').hide();
        $(this).find('.checked').show();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add a class to the clicked element named "clicked". On the hover out function, it checks if the element has til class assigned or not. If class is not present, it will animate back out to 70% opacity.

```
$(".opacity-change img").css('opacity','0.7');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".opacity-change img").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
    },
    function() {
        if ( !$(this).hasClass( 'clicked' ) ){
            $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.7 }, 500); 
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.profiles a').bind('click',function(){
        $('.checked').hide();
        $('.clicked').css("opacity", 0.7).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).find('.checked').show();
        $(this).addClass( 'clicked' );
    });
});
```

Comment: Works a treat! thanks however 1 thing i have noticed is that we have around 8 of these and if i click other the previous opacity stays at 100% can we revert the others to 70& again if another is clicked?

Comment: also if i just hover and hover out of one that is not clicked the opacity stays at 100% - thanks for all your help

Comment: Give me 2 secs to write it for  you

Comment: Thanks Ole your a star!

Comment: I edited my answer now. Now adding a class to the element instead

Comment: Only seems to ever add the class on the first on you click when you click on teh others does not add the class to those? sorry and thanks for your help

Comment: It should be `$('.clicked').css("opacity", 0.7).removeClass('clicked');`

Comment: Seems to work fine now since i added the CSS .switch-profile.clicked div img {
 opacity: 1 !important;
} thanks for helping out on this works great! :)